# Using a VelocityTracker to calculate the velocity of one specific pointer in a multitouch app

Tags: java, android, input

My app allows multiple pointers to interact with it at once.

I would like to use a `VelocityTracker` to calculate the velocity of one particular pointer when multiple fingers on on the touchscreen. By default, the `VelocityTracker` factors in all active pointers, so a stationary pointer can make the velocity seem too low if all I care about is a different pointer, which is moving.

I tried this:

```
if (motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                || motionEvent.getPointerId(motionEvent.getActionIndex()) == desiredPointerId)
{
    velocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
}
```

In this way, I only pass the `MotionEvent` to the `VelocityTracker` if the new action is from my `desiredPointerId` which I wish to track, or if it is a `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` (which is often categorized under a different Id if it affects multiple pointers).

But this way, on a `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` event, all pointer information gets passed, and The `VelocityTracker` takes into account other pointers! What should I do?

(Note: the purpose of this dummy question is to teach a neat `VelocityTracker` trick.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! Try this:

```
if (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                || motionEvent.getPointerId(motionEvent.getActionIndex()) == desiredPointerId)
    {
        // Create a dummy MotionEvent with only the data of the active pointer, and feed that into the VelocityTracker --
        // so our velocity is calculated only with respect to the active pointer, and not some weird average of all the pointers.
        // (Read: very clever hack!)
        MotionEvent culledMotionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent.getDownTime(), motionEvent.getEventTime(),
                motionEvent.getActionMasked(), // Using getAction() here will cause a nasty crash (unknown reason).
                motionEvent.getX(motionEvent.findPointerIndex(desiredPointerId)),
                motionEvent.getY(motionEvent.findPointerIndex(desiredPointerId)),
                motionEvent.getMetaState());
        velocityTracker.addMovement(culledMotionEvent);
        culledMotionEvent.recycle();
    }
```

As you can see, we create a fake MotionEvent and only put into it the data of our `desiredPointerId`! So the `VelocityTracker` only accounts for the data we want.